# 2 cycle engine has spark and new carb won't start

Tags: engine, scooter, two-stroke

I have a 49cc 2cycle engine that I replaced the carb on. It has fresh gas and
appears to have a spark.  I can't get it to fire even if I put some starter fluid in the air intake. It seems to have compression.  The motor has sat for a few years in a garage, it did have old gas that I clean out of the tank.

Comment: How did you check if it has spark? Also, while the carb is important, *most* small 2-stroke motors have a reed valve which allows the air/fuel to flow one way (through the carb, into the crank case, then into the cylinder). Have you looked at this? Is the prime bulb good? Is the choke mechanism working?

Comment: You might need to tune the carb.  I put on new carb on my trimmer and it was way out of tune.  Turn the low screw in to seat, then out 1.5 turns.  This should be good enough to get it to get it to start.